# "Go lower than $100 on something" or "go lower than $100 for something"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you please tell which preposition, *on* or *for*, it is correct and natural to use in the context below?

> Unfortunately I can't go lower than $100 **on**/**for** that phone.

What I'm trying to say is that I can't sell for a price lower than $100.

Comment: "For" sounds better to me, but for colloquial speaking/haggling, "on" is fine too.

Comment: It might be less common, but there wouldn't be anything wrong with using ***with*** here. And possibly other prepositions - English is often pretty flexible about such usages, particularly in relatively "slangy" contexts such as the example above. Which would be more "properly" expressed by *I can't **accept less** than $100 **for** that phone* (where the preference for only using ***for*** is *much* stronger).